# How can I display the errors from an POST Response in the UI?

Tags: json, angular

Upon an invalid login, the following response is received.

```
Response {
  _body: "{
      "email": ["The email field is required."],
      "password":["The password field is required."]
     }",
  status: 422, ok: false, statusText: "Unprocessable Entity", headers: Headers
}
```

I want to display the errors to the user in the UI. Here's my implementation of the observable.

**`Class`**

```
export class LoginPage
{
  signInData: any[];
  errors:     any[];
  ...

  this.userService.signIn(form.value.email, form.value.password)
  .subscribe(
    data => this.signedInData = data,
    error => this.errors = error._body
   );
}
```

I simply set the retrieved _body object to this.errors. If I try to display the errors as follows,

**`Template`**

```
 <ul *ngFor="let error of errors">           
   <li>{{error}}</li>
 </ul>
```

I get the following error.

> Error in ./LoginPage class LoginPage - inline template:30:19 caused by: Cannot find a differ supporting object '{"email":["The email field is required."],"password":["The password field is required."]}' of type 'string'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.

How do I handle this?

**`UPDATE`**

If I change the subscription to:

```
this.userService.signIn(form.value.email, form.value.password)
  .subscribe(
    data => this.signedInData = data,
    error => this.errors.push(error._body)
);

<ul *ngFor="let error of errors">           
   <li>{{error}}</li>
</ul>
```

[image]

It successfully prints the error object. Now I would need to access the values in the object, remove the braces and print the values. How?

**`WORKING CODE`**

Thanks to @echonax, I am able to parse the data to JSON, check if it exists and then push into the errors array one by one.

```
this.userService.signIn(form.value.email, form.value.password)
.subscribe(
  data => this.signedInData = data,
  error =>
  {
        let err = JSON.parse(error._body);
        if(err && err.email && err.email[0]){
          this.errors.push(err.email[0]);
        }
        if(err && err.password && err.password[0]){
          this.errors.push(err.password[0]);
        }  
  }
);

<ul *ngFor="let error of errors">           
   <li>{{error}}</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`*ngFor` only supports iterables like `Arrays`

Your `error.body` is an object

```
"{
    "email": ["The email field is required."],
    "password":["The password field is required."]
 }"
```

So it's not compatible to use with `*ngFor`

Instead of using

```
<ul *ngFor="let error of errors">           
   <li>{{error}}</li>
</ul>
```

Try:

```
<span>{{errors | json}}</span>
```

like @Aravind has mentioned

If you want to select them individually, something like this might work:

```
<span>{{errors?.email[0]}}</span>
<span>{{errors?.password[0]}}</span>
```

**Update**

if

`this.errors.push(error._body)` works

in order to get the values individually; try:

```
this.userService.signIn(form.value.email, form.value.password)
  .subscribe(
    (data) => this.signedInData = data,
    (error) => {
                 error = JSON.parse(error._body);
                 if(error._body && error._body.email && error._body.email[0]){
                   this.errors.push(error._body.email[0]);
                 }
                 if(error._body && error._body.password && error._body.password[0]){
                   this.errors.push(error._body.password[0]);
                 }                     
               }
);

<ul *ngFor="let error of errors">           
   <li>{{error}}</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I see where I went wrong there. `{{ errors | json }}` does print the whole object. Yes, I need to print them individually. If I implement `{{ signInErrors?.email[0] }}` for the same error, I get `Error in ./LoginPage class LoginPage - inline template:31:23 caused by: Cannot read property '0' of undefined` - despite the email field still being empty.

Comment: For `{{errors?.email}}`, it seems to print nothing at all. Plus, there may or may not be an `email` property in the object.

Comment: @anonym If it doesn't have that property of course it will not print it. But it does and not print it then we have a problem

Comment: That's right, but it's nt printing it. So if I console.log(this.errors), I get the following. --- `Array[1] 0 :
"{"email":["The email field is required."],"password":["The password field is required."]}" length: 1 __proto__:Array[0]`. errors is an array with a single object.

Comment: It seems correct, and that should've been it. But it still outputs `Cannot read property '0' of undefined`.

Comment: Nothing happens as the if conditions don't return true which is because error._body.email[0] is undefined, for some reason. If I `error => { console.log(error._body); }` I successfully get the error object `{"email":["The email field is required."],"password":["The password field is required."]}` but if I do `error => { console.log(error._body.email[0])` } it outputs `undefined`. That's surprising!

Comment: @anonym how about now? I've added `error = JSON.parse(error._body);`

Answer (score 2):

You are referring to wrong variable

```
<ul *ngFor="let error of error">           
   <li>{{error.email}}</li>
 </ul>
```

You are storing the errors in the `errors` variable and you refer to `signInErrors`.

Note: You should display it as json as you cannot predict what will be error from service.

```
<span>{{error |json }}</span>
```

Update 1 : 
You should be converting to json() as below

```
this.userService.signIn(form.value.email, form.value.password)
  .subscribe(
    data => this.signedInData = data,
    error => this.errors = JSON.parse(error._body)
   );
```

Comment: That was a typo, and the problem persists. I tried adding the `json` pipe as you sugggested, and I get the same error with escaped quotation marks.

`ION: Error in ./LoginPage class LoginPage - inline template:30:17 caused by: Cannot find a differ supporting object '"{\"email\":[\"The email field is required.\"],\"password\":[\"The password field is required.\"]}"' of type 'string'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.`

Comment: Thanks for your time. Looks like that must've been what I missed. But now it yields a similar error: `EXCEPTION: Error in ./LoginPage class LoginPage - inline template:30:17 caused by: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.`

Comment: you need more help or is the issue fixed?

Comment: is there a specific format in which any error will be returned. by this I mean `export interface errorClass` can we use a generic one?

Comment: so is the issue fixed or need help?

Comment: It's successfully done and I've updated the question. Thanks for the help.